# React useEffect and useState with timer behaving very weird

Tags: reactjs

Can someone help shine some light on the following issue I am having?  The first time it runs it runs as designed and counts down (note set to 20000 for testing will be 1 second after it works).   However, after all other iteration the `setBeacon(900000)` goes haywire and the timeout is super fast.   I am building a stand alone app to see if it is a hook issue with other hooks.

```
 import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef} from 'react';
 import { useApi } from '../api/ApiCustomHook';
 import { getSubmitterEmpDetailsHeaders } from '../api/api'; 

 const SessionBeacon = (userObj) => {    
   const { invokeFetchCall } = useApi();  
   const [beacon, setBeacon] = useState(900000);

  useEffect(() => {
     const timer = setTimeout(() => {setBeacon(beacon - 20000)}, 1000);      
     console.log("Time Remaing beacon = " + beacon);
     if (beacon <= 600000) {        
         let getEmpServiceHeaders = getSubmitterEmpDetailsHeaders(
         userObj.userId
    );
    invokeFetchCall(
      getEmpServiceHeaders.url,
      getEmpServiceHeaders.fetchData 
    ); 

    console.log("Beacon after setBeacon is beacon = " + beacon);           
    return setBeacon(900000);
  }
}); 

return (  
        <div>
        Beacon Timer - {beacon}
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />            
        </div>
  )
 }

 export default SessionBeacon;
```

Comment: I don't see any `clearTimeout(timer)`, which means your timer will non stop with a lot of leaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear the timer when you reset the beacon.

```
.
.
.
useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setBeacon(beacon - 20000);
    }, 1000);
    console.log("Time Remaing beacon = " + beacon);
    if (beacon <= 600000) {
      .
      .
      .
      clearTimeout(timer);
      console.log("Beacon after setBeacon is beacon = " + beacon);
      return setBeacon(900000);
    }
  });
.
.
.
```